# Cómo combinar tablas iguales?

Tags: sql-server, select, join, union, inner

Tengo dos tablas que tienen la misma información y al momento de generar el INNER JOIN me crea mas columnas pero necesito es filas. Es decir

Tengo la Tabla PersonaD

| ID | NOMBRE_1 | APELLIDO_1 | CIUDAD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | JAIME | PERDOMO | BOGOTA |
| 3 | ANDRES | RAMIREZ | FUSA |
| 4 | FELIPE | FERNANDEZ | CHIA |

Y adicional tengo la tabla PersonaV

| ID | NOMBRE_1 | APELLIDO_1 | CIUDAD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | JAIME | PERDOMO | GIRARDOT |
| 3 | ANDRES | RAMIREZ | MELGAR |
| 4 | FELIPE | FERNANDEZ | NILO |

Al realizar el INNER JOIN

SELECT *FROM PersonaD as PD INNER JOIN PersonaV as PV ON PD.ID = PV.ID

Me da el siguiente resultado

| PD.ID | PD.NOMBRE_1 | PD.APELLIDO_1 | PD.CIUDAD | PV.ID | PV.NOMBRE_1 | PV.APELLIDO_1 | PV.CIUDAD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | JAIME | PERDOMO | BOGOTA | 2 | JAIME | PERDOMO | GIRARDOT |
| 3 | ANDRES | RAMIREZ | FUSA | 3 | ANDRES | RAMIREZ | MELGAR |
| 4 | FELIPE | FERNANDEZ | CHIA | 4 | FELIPE | FERNANDEZ | NILO |

Pero lo que necesito es que me de el resultado en filas diferentes, es decir:

| ID | NOMBRE_1 | APELLIDO_1 | CIUDAD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | JAIME | PERDOMO | BOGOTA |
| 2 | JAIME | PERDOMO | GIRARDOT |
| 3 | ANDRES | RAMIREZ | FUSA |
| 3 | ANDRES | RAMIREZ | MELGAR |
| 4 | FELIPE | FERNANDEZ | CHIA |
| 4 | FELIPE | FERNANDEZ | NILO |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenidx a SOes.

La respuesta está en las etiquetas que usaste.

```
SELECT * FROM PersonaD as PD 
UNION
SELECT * FROM PersonaV as PV
```

Eso une la proyección de cada consulta en un único conjunto resultado, siempre y cuando las columnas sean iguales, como en este caso.

Comment: Lo ideal es usar UNION ALL porque UNION elimina duplicados. A menos de que ese sea el objetivo.